# What is RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> and how it is different from RecyclerView.Adapter in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm learning RecyclerView and in [developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)'s site the Adapter class extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>`. The implementation shows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private String[] mDataset;


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;
    public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        textView = v;
    }
}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
}
```

And in this [tutorial](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/android-fundamentals-working-with-the-recyclerview-adapter-and-viewholder-pattern), the adapter class extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`. The implementation is:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<SimpleViewModel> models = new ArrayList<>();


public SimpleAdapter(final List<SimpleViewModel> viewModels) {
    if (viewModels != null) {
        this.models.addAll(viewModels);
    }
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ((SimpleViewHolder) holder).bindData(models.get(position));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
    return R.layout.item_simple_itemview;
}
}
```

So what is the difference between `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` and what is the syntax<> in `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>` means in this case? I know it stands for generics. When should I use this?

Comment: If a class is a generic type, you should always specify the type arguments. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: So I should use "public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder>" instead of "public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter "? It works both ways.

Comment: You should use the first, though you'd obviously replace the type argument with whatever type your application is using. While it works both ways they are not equivalent—the second is a _raw type_. See the Q&A I linked in my previous comment for more information about raw types and why they should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the difference between RecyclerView.Adapter< MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> and RecyclerView.Adapter and what is the syntax<> in RecyclerView.Adapter means in this case? I know it stands for generics. When should I use this?

First, let's review the definition of the `Adapter` class. It's defined within `RecyclerView` as so:

```
public abstract static class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder>
```

So what does the "generics" part of this mean? It means the Adapter class operates on some class type (`VH`) that must be a descendant of the class `ViewHolder`. This is known as a *[Bounded Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)* and ensures that the type of of class the adapter is working with is guaranteed to be a type of `ViewHolder`.

As you see with the example on the developer's site you posted, when you create your own adapter that specifies the type of the ViewHolder as `MyViewHolder`, then the methods you have to override in the adapter explicitly declare that type in their signatures. For example, the return type for `onCreateViewHolder` is explicitly set to `MyViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

---

Alternatively, the tutorial you posted does *not* specify a type.

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
```

When you extend a class that expects a generic type and don't specify one, *the compiler defaults to the least common denominator* - that is, the class type lowest in the inheritance hierarchy that will guarantee the class can be used as designed. Because the Adapter's generic type is defined as `VH extends ViewHolder`, the compiler knows that the class type must be *at least* a `ViewHolder` and defaults to that. Hence, the same method overriden for this example returns `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` instead of `MyViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}
```

If `RecyclerView.Adapter` was defined as `Adapter<VH>` (no bounded type), and you extended it without specifying the type, the type would default to `Object` (the root class of all Java classes):

```
@Override
public Object onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}
```

---

So, finally, why use one instead of the other? Generally speaking: *you should always specify the type for a generic class*. This guarantees you type-safety. In the tutorial example, you could return the wrong type of view holder which would compile but crash at runtime:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);

    // Returning wrong view holder, but because it still extends ViewHolder and
    // that is all this method requires, this compiles
    return new SomeOtherViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // Above we created a SomeOtherViewHolder but here we're expecting a SimpleViewHolder
    // This will crash trying to cast to the wrong type
    ((SimpleViewHolder) holder).bindData(models.get(position));
}
```

It's impossible to make this mistake in the first example though because the `ViewHolder` type is declared explicitly:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

    // Trying to return SomeOtherViewHolder when method expects MyViewHolder
    // Compiler's like (*waves finger*) "nuh-uh, not on my watch" and fails
    // to compile
    SomeOtherViewHolder vh = new SomeOtherViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Notice here that holder is explicitly of MyViewHolder type and casting
    // is not necessary! That's TYPE SAFETY y'all.
    holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);
}
```

Because you specify the *explicit*, *concrete* type you expect, you cannot accidentally return the wrong type, you do not need to cast, and you can leverage all of the public methods defined in your custom `ViewHolder` class.

Hope that helps!